# Array Multiplication in Julia

Tags: arrays, types, multiplication, julia

I'm trying to do something that I believe should be relatively simple in Julia, but I can't seem to find any mention of this problem.

Basically what I've got is an `mxn` matrix, and an `nx1` vector. What I would like to do is multiply the vector against the matrix, elementwise, but along the axis such that every element of the matrix is multiplied.

In `numpy` for instance this would be:

```
np.multiply(array, vector)
```

Is there any way to do this in Julia?

I tried just extending the vector to fill an array:

```
projection = 1:size(matrix)[1]
weight_change = hcat(map(x -> vector, projection))
```

but that yields something with a type of `Array{Array{Float64, 2}, 2}`, when what I really need is just `Array{Float64, 2}`, which means that an elementwise multiplication won't really work.

Is there any way to either fix my approach or remedy my bugged solution?

Comment: `np.multiply(array, vector, axis=0)` isn't valid `numpy`, is it?

Comment: @DSM Oh, dorp, you're totally right, doesn't take an axis element, just does it automatically.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're looking for the `.*` element-wise, broadcasting multiply operator:

```
julia> A = [ i + j*im for i=1:3, j=1:4 ]
3x4 Array{Complex{Int64},2}:
 1+1im  1+2im  1+3im  1+4im
 2+1im  2+2im  2+3im  2+4im
 3+1im  3+2im  3+3im  3+4im

julia> v = [1:4]
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4

julia> w = [1:3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> A .* w
3x4 Array{Complex{Int64},2}:
 1+1im  1+2im  1+3im   1+4im
 4+2im  4+4im  4+6im   4+8im
 9+3im  9+6im  9+9im  9+12im

julia> A .* v'
3x4 Array{Complex{Int64},2}:
 1+1im  2+4im  3+9im   4+16im
 2+1im  4+4im  6+9im   8+16im
 3+1im  6+4im  9+9im  12+16im
```

Comment: I'm... a little embarrassed that this isn't the first place my mind went, but thank you very much for answering my question.